# Unexpected nulls in ViewModel on Form Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, viewmodel

Hello I have method that populates a viewmodel that looks like this

```
foreach (ItemHasParts ihp in item.IHP)
            {
                Part part = db.Parts.Find(ihp.PartID);
              
                vm.Parts.Add(new ItemPartViewModel
                {
                    ID = part.ID,
                    PartID = part.PartID,
                    PartLink = part.PartIDLink,
                    MFGNumber = part.MFG_number,
                    QtyInItem = ihp.qty,
                    OnHand = part.On_Hand,
                    OnWorkOrder = part.On_Order_Count(true, true),
                    Committed = part.CommittedCount(true, true),
                    FSTK = part.FSTK,
                    PartName = part.Name,
                    SelectedActionType = PartActionType.Transfer
                });
            }
```

Here is the Post Method where I am checking the locals,

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SpecialOrderSelection(ItemViewModel model)
        {
            //list of transfers
            //list of harvests
            //list of disposals      
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                JobOrder jobOrder = db.JobOrders.Find(model.Id);
                if (jobOrder == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                ViewBag.JobOrderID = jobOrder.ID;
                // do whatever with 'model' and return or redirect to a View
            }

            ViewBag.submitted = true;
            return View(model);     

        }
```

Some of them have the correct values afterwards but some upon postback, for Example PartID are returning null even though Part.partID is not null.

Why is this?

Comment: There is not enough information to solve this puzzle. What is important and missing is how your form looks in HTML. It seems that there are two types: `ItemViewModel` and `ItemPartViewModel`.  It appears that the form post is sending an instance of `ItemViewModel` to the controller action, `SpecialOrderSelection`.  You should not expect that `Parts` collection to be hydrated automatically.

Comment: @GlennFerrie why would some of the data be correctly populated then. Wouldn't everything be null?

Comment: Your form posts data to the controller action, ASP.NET interprets that form post body and, by convention, populates the fields in your model based on a name match.  If you switch the type of your input argument from `InputViewModel` to `FormCollection` you will see more precisely what the form is sending to the controller.

Comment: @GlennFerrie hmm do you think an AJAX post might be a good option then?

Comment: I think that would work nicely.  then you can post a more complex object.

Comment: @GlennFerrie Okay I tried it with AJAX but it is returning null data now, maybe you can take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62898140/ajax-post-is-returning-null-data-to-the-controller