# AJAX POST is returning NULL data to the controller

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hello I have an AJAX POST that is returning null data to my Controller.

Here is my AJAX code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@IGT.baseUrl/JODetails/SpecialOrderSummary',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST'
        });
    });
});
```

And here is my controller

```
public ActionResult SpecialOrderSummary(ItemViewModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    JobOrder jobOrder = db.JobOrders.Find(model.Id);
    if (jobOrder == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Here is my ItemViewModel

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
    public IList<ItemPartViewModel> Parts { get; set; }
    public IList<ItemComponentViewModel> Components{ get; set; }
    public IList<ComponentPartViewModel> ComponentParts { get; set; }
    public IList<ComponentSubCompViewModel> ComponentSubComps { get; set; }
    public IList<SubCompPartViewModel> SubCompParts { get; set; }

    public IList<SubCompSubCompViewModel> SubCompSubComps { get; set; }
    public IList<SubCompSubCompPartViewModel> SubCompSubCompParts { get; set; }
}
```

It's returning the model but the the model has empty data, why is this?

I had originally done a normal POST but the post was missing some key data as you can see in [Unexpected nulls in ViewModel on Form Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62883899/unexpected-nulls-in-viewmodel-on-form-post?noredirect=1#comment111206623_62883899)

Comment: Assuming the model is correct, you're missing `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` in your Ajax call.

Comment: There isnt alot of information in your snippets here. Have you checked the developer console to make sure your ajax is sending the correct data? have you set debug breakpoints in your controller to check the data received.

Comment: @tstrand66 Yeah I set debug breakpoints in the controller, it is sending a model but the data in it is null. Not exactly sure how to check the developer console

Comment: @derloopkat I tried what you suggested but still getting null data, and okay I added in my model

Comment: @JoshFontaine in your browser hit f12 then check the network tab. you should be able to see the body of data posted. if its empty there is your failure, if its valid then the model binder for your controller is failing.

Comment: @JoshFontaine, you have posted this question a number of times before. The problem is your model not matching the Post. In other word, the fields on the form are different than the properties in your model.

Comment: @derloopkat a user suggested I try it using AJAX, why would the model not be matching the post?

Comment: @derloopkat so should I be doing a bind?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a JSON object when you make the AJAX call.

I typically use an array, where you have used `IList<T>` in your `ItemViewModel` -- I think it just makes the serialization story simpler.

Here is some sample code to get you started.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {

        // build the json object from the elements in the form... 

        // this is a sample object that would work well with your current model... 
        var payload = {
            "Id": 5,
            "JobId": 6,
            "ItemId": "Item0987", 
            "ItemName": "Some Sample Item Name",
            "MFGNumber": "B1235456",
            "Parts": [
                { "Id": "PartA", "PartName": "Sample Part A" },
                { "Id": "PartB", "PartName": "Sample Part B" }
            ]
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "@IGT.baseUrl/JODetails/SpecialOrderSummary",
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",            
            type: "POST", 
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, 
            error: function (req, status, err) {
                console.error(err);
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function() {
                   console.error( "page not found" );
                },
                500: function() {
                   console.error( "server error" );
                },
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I added some error handling to the `$.ajax` call to help you catch other issues besides the form serialization.